# arranging strings from one data frame based on another one

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this one

```
df1<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(8L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("A0A061AKW6;Q19219;A0A061AJ82;Q7JLR4", "A0A061AL89;A0A061AJK8;Q21920-2;Q21920-7;Q21920", 
"C1P641;C1P640;A0A061AD21;G5EEV6", "O16276", "O16520-2", "O17323-2", 
"O17395", "O17403", "Q22501;A0A061AE05"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

My second data from looks like this

```
df2<- structure(list(From = structure(c(12L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 
9L, 15L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 16L, 6L, 4L, 14L), .Label = c("A0A061AD21", 
"A0A061AE05", "A0A061AJ82", "A0A061AJK8", "A0A061AKW6", "A0A061AL89", 
"C1P640", "C1P641", "G5EEV6", "O16276", "O17395", "O17403", "Q19219", 
"Q21920", "Q22501", "Q7JLR4"), class = "factor"), To = structure(c(4L, 
8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("aat-3", 
"CELE_F08G5.3", "CELE_R11A8.7", "cpsf-2", "epi-1", "pps-1", "R11A8.7", 
"ugt-61"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("From", "To"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

df2 is taken from df1 but some information are added and some are removed . I want to reconstruct the df2 like df1 and arrange the column named To based on that

So the output should look like this

```
From                                             To
O17403                                          cpsf-2
O16276                                          ugt-61
O16520-2                                          -
O17395                                          aat-3
O17323-2                                          -
C1P641;C1P640;A0A061AD21;G5EEV6                  epi-1
Q22501;A0A061AE05                                pps-1
A0A061AKW6;Q19219;A0A061AJ82;Q7JLR4              CELE_F08G5.3
A0A061AL89;A0A061AJK8;Q21920-2;Q21920-7;Q21920   CELE_R11A8.7; R11AB.7
```

It means we have O17403 in df2 and was only one string in df1, so it stays the same. O16276 was only one string in a raw in df1 so it also stays the same 
O16520-2 was in df1 was not in df2 so in column named to a hyphen 
the same for the rest until C1P641;C1P640;A0A061AD21;G5EEV6  are all in the same row of df1 and their To is the same, so we put them the same as df1 and just add one epi-1

Probably the best is to put df1 as template and then parse the To to it , those that are in df2, parse their To , those that are not only a hyphen

It is very complicated, I even could not think how to do it.I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I split the semicolon delimited strings and created a nested for-for-if-if loop.

Here's the logic behind the loop which runs against the split string's data.frame (`tmp`):

1. Fix data classes (i.e. change factor to character to avoid conflicting level sets) and append a temporary `To` column to `tmp`
2. For each column and row of `tmp` start by seeing if a cell contains a valid string for matching and a matched value in `df2$To`, if not, go to the next iteration
3. If it does then look at the matching value in `To` from `df2`, checking to see if we already have the matched value in `tmp$To` (if so, go to next iteration)
4. If there's a new matched value in `df2$To` then put it in the correspond cell of `tmp$To`, prepending it with any preceeding matches and semicolons if it is not the first match for that row

   ```
   df1$V1   <- as.character(df1$V1)
   df2$From <- as.character(df2$From)
   df2$To   <- as.character(df2$To)

   library(stringr)
   tmp <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(df1$V1, ";",n=5), stringsAsFactors = F)

   tmp$To <- as.character(NA)
   for(j in 1:nrow(tmp)){
     for(i in 1:ncol(tmp)){
       if(length(df2$To[df2$From == tmp[j,i]]) == 0 | is.null(tmp[j,i])){
         next
       } else if(length(df2$To[df2$From == tmp[j,i]] ) == 1 & !is.na(tmp[j,i])){
           if(is.na(tmp$To[j]) | tmp$To[j] == df2$To[df2$From == tmp[j,i]]){
             tmp$To[j] <- df2$To[df2$From == tmp[j,i] ]
           } else{
             tmp$To[j] <- paste(tmp$To[j],";",df2$To[df2$From == tmp[j,i] ], sep="")
           }
       } else{
         next
       }
     }
   }

   df1 <- data.frame(From=df1$V1, To=tmp$To)
   df1
   ```

   > ```
   >                                             From                   To
   > 1                                         O17403               cpsf-2
   > 2                                         O16276               ugt-61
   > 3                                       O16520-2                 <NA>
   > 4                                         O17395                aat-3
   > 5                                       O17323-2                 <NA>
   > 6                C1P641;C1P640;A0A061AD21;G5EEV6                epi-1
   > 7                              Q22501;A0A061AE05                pps-1
   > 8            A0A061AKW6;Q19219;A0A061AJ82;Q7JLR4         CELE_F08G5.3
   > 9 A0A061AL89;A0A061AJK8;Q21920-2;Q21920-7;Q21920 CELE_R11A8.7;R11A8.7
   > ```

Comment: why did you down voted my question? please give me sometime I will go through your answer and accept it. I really appreciate your effort and time Thanks but please give me some time

Comment: @nik You're talking to me? I didn't downvote it. I wouldn't downvote a question I've answered.

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks , the first problem I found is 'str_split_fixed(df1$V1, ";",n=5)' in this case we have 5 strings in one row , but in reality sometimes we have 40 or ... which I don't know in advance

Comment: @Hack-R I liked it already, the rest of the code is just great!. however, I have a small request to ask. what if I had df1 also with two columns V1 and To . the V1 is the same but the To is not complete , means in front of some of the V1 strings we have strings and in front of some we don't have. so we want to complete it based on df2. do you think it is easy to do ?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use the `splitstackshape` package (use `cSplit`).  I converted the factors to character strings to simplify (and get rid of warnings).

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)      # cSplit from 'splitstackshape' returns a 'data.table'.
library(splitstackshape)

### Remove the factors for convenience of manipulation
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(From = as.character(V1))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(From = as.character(From), To = as.character(To))

### 'cSplit' will split on ';' and create a new row for each item. The
### original 'From' column is kept around as cSplit removes the split column.
### 'rn' (row number) is used for ordering later.
cSplit(df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number(), From_temp = From),
       "From_temp", sep = ";", direction = "long", drop = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE) %>%
    left_join(df2, by = c(From_temp = 'From')) %>% # Join to 'df2' to get the 'To' column
    group_by(From, rn)                         %>% # Group by original 'From' column.
    summarise(To = paste(sort(unique(na.omit(To))), collapse = ';'), # Create 'To' by joining 'To' Values
              To = ifelse(To=='', '-', To))    %>% # Set empty values to '-'
    ungroup                                    %>%
    arrange(rn)                                %>% # Sort by original row number and
    select(-rn)                                    # remove 'rn' column.

##                                             From                   To
##                                            <chr>                <chr>
## 1                                         O17403               cpsf-2
## 2                                         O16276               ugt-61
## 3                                       O16520-2                    -
## 4                                         O17395                aat-3
## 5                                       O17323-2                    -
## 6                C1P641;C1P640;A0A061AD21;G5EEV6                epi-1
## 7                              Q22501;A0A061AE05                pps-1
## 8            A0A061AKW6;Q19219;A0A061AJ82;Q7JLR4         CELE_F08G5.3
## 9 A0A061AL89;A0A061AJK8;Q21920-2;Q21920-7;Q21920 CELE_R11A8.7;R11A8.7
```

There may be a cleaner way to do with `dplyr` that doesn't require the `splitstackshape`.

Comment: thanks , it is like a clock ! please give me time to go through it. I liked your answer already anyway .

Comment: @nik I forgot to mention, I renamed the `V1` column to `From`

Comment: what if I had df1 also with two columns V1 and To . the V1 is the same but the To is not complete , means in front of some of the V1 strings we have strings and in front of some we don't have. so we want to complete it based on df2. do you think it is easy to do ? If you have a solution for it, I can even ask a separate question

Comment: @nik You should really either make this part of the question or ask a separate question.  You could add this new use case into the question with input and desired output.

Comment: @nik You can accept whatever answer you feel answers your question best.  Sometimes (in this case or not) multiple yet different answers will be "tied" for best but you have to pick only one (or none if they aren't what you are looking for).  It is your choice and others should ok with that.  If a non-selected answer is best for most people it will get more up votes.  So in short, accepting the other answer if perfectly fine.

Comment: I wait until one gets more vote so I will accept that therefore the other won't be sad ! however, i liked your answer and your behave is great ! thanks